# Multicollinearity when estimating a gravity model

Tags: regression, least-squares, multicollinearity, cross-section

everyone!

I am estimating a gravity model in order to analyze the impacts of tighter environmental regulations on international trade. More specifically, I am analyzing Brazil's trade flow.

My (linearized) model is as follows:

$ \ln(EXP) = \ln(GDP_O) +  \ln(GDP_D) +  \ln(POP_O) + \ln(POP_D) + \dots $

In other words, the exports from Brazil (origin) to a country D (destination) depend on both countries GDPs,Populations, Total Area and  another couple of variables.

My problem is: because Brazil is the origin for the exports to all other countries, GDP_O, POP_O and any other variables representing Brazilian data will be equal for all observations and as such there will be perfect multicollinearity.

How do I circumvent this? Every gravity model uses both the exporter and importer variables in order to explain the bilateral trade flow.

EDIT: See for instance the estimation carried out here: [Van Beers](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DczfoFI_mkI8Tm4H0WcaVZTz9ZXLGb2K/view?usp=drivesdk)

I appreciate any help!

Kind regards,
Pedro

Comment: I think you are suggesting modifying your data. I don't see how that could be justified.

Comment: It's quite the opposite: I want to use all of my data, just as it is. Like I said, every paper estimates their gravity equations including variables for the importer and the exporter. However, I cannot understand how to actually do that, since every row containing Brazil as exporter, for instance, will have the values for GDP_O, POP_O, etc, which would cause perfect multicollinearity. What am I missing?

Comment: So if you are right about a perfect linear relationship there is redundancy and the one way around it is to reduce the number of predictors. The reason I thought you wanted to modify the data would be if you would insist on using all the predictors.

Comment: But how do people estimate using all those variables? I don't see any way of including variables from both countries and yet that is what is done

Comment: The problem is that you can find a solution but the estimates of the regression coefficients will not be unique.

Comment: How did the author estimated his model here? I'm honestly lost. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DczfoFI_mkI8Tm4H0WcaVZTz9ZXLGb2K/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100070/discussion-between-pedro-cunha-and-michael-chernick).